# how to pool different shaped convolutional layer outputs to a fixed shape to pass for Fully connected layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have different sized input images, and I am passing them through the Conv layers in a CNN after which I should connect the Conv outputs to a Fully Connected Layer for classification.

Since the process has to be vectorised the outputs have to be of same shape so that a batch of images could be used for forward pass. And hence this problem of having same shape for all images at the input of Fully Connected layer.

But since my input images are of different shape my final Conv layer gives different shaped outputs, how do I pool/reshape the different shaped outputs from Last Conv Layer to a fixed shape so that they can be connected to immediate FCN layer?

Also, I have considered reshaping images to fixed size before processing but have performance[accuracy] issues as my input images vary in large[So, trying this].

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are consistent across examples (i.e. if `inputs = image1, image2`, then all your `image1`s are the same size, all your `image2`s are the same size, but `image1.shape` isn't necessarily the same as `image2` you could just flatten your final conv outputs and concatenate the results before passing to a dense layer.

```
conv1_out = conv_network1(image1)
conv2_out = conv_network2(image2)              # could be same network
flat1 = tf.layers.flatten(conv1_out)
flat2 = tf.layers.flatten(conv2_out)
dense_in = tf.concat((flat1, flat2), axis=1)
dense_out = tf.layers.dense(dense_in, units)
```

Alternatively, if your images are different sizes across batches if you have a large number of spatial features spatial pooling is another popular option.

```
flat1 = tf.reduce_mean(conv1_out, axis=(1, 2))
flat2 = tf.reduce_mean(conv2_out, axis=(1, 2))
```

You can also use max pooling, though the behaviour is subtly different.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have different shapes of images across my complete dataset, not any two images might be of same shape (height * width), so being consistent across batches or within batches is also not possible.

Comment: In that case, either spatial pooling or resizing (interpolating or padding/cropping) are your only options. You'll need sizes to be consistent across a batch at least. While you could hypothetically get around this with a batch size of 1, I'd advise against it. If it's possible/reasonable, resizing your inputs to a uniform shape would probably be best. If you're doing spatial pooling, the difference in spatial information probably won't affect this too much (since you toss it all out when you pool anyway).